# .NET MAUI Toolkit StatusBarBehavior how to set StatusBarStyle depending on AppTheme

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I want to set the StatusBarStyle depending on my theme. I did change the background color successfully, but I can't set the StatusBarStyle depending on the theme.
I tried the following:

```
<Shell.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="{ AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource SunMeWhite}, Dark={StaticResource SunMeBlack} }"
                               StatusBarStyle="{ AppThemeBinding Light={Resource DarkContent}, Dark={Resource LightContent} }" />
</Shell.Behaviors>
```

Then this:

```
<Shell.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="{ AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource SunMeWhite}, Dark={StaticResource SunMeBlack} }"
                               StatusBarStyle="{ AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource SunMeBlack}, Dark={StaticResource SunMeWhite} }" />
</Shell.Behaviors>
```

None worked. SunMeBlack and SunMeWhite are keys in the color.xaml file:

```
<Color x:Key="SunMeWhite">#FFFFFF</Color>
<Color x:Key="SunMeBlack">#000000</Color>
```

thnx

Answer (score 1):

```
<Shell.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="{ AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource SunMeWhite}, Dark={StaticResource SunMeBlack} }"
                               StatusBarStyle="{ AppThemeBinding Light=DarkContent, Dark=LightContent }" />
</Shell.Behaviors>
```